# Pipeline doesnt open Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

so I'm trying to make things cleaner with use of items and pipelines. For now my settings for pipelines are (in settings.py):

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'scrapybot.pipelines.CsvPipeline': 300,
}
```

Pipelines content (as a test) in pipelines.py into the same folder than settings :

```
class CsvPipeline(object):
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    print("it works")
    return item
```

I launch my two spiders from a single file named core, which is in the same folder than pipelines and settings :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from spiders.carrefour_bot import CarrefourSpider
from spiders.ebay_bot import EbaySpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl(CarrefourSpider)
process.crawl(EbaySpider)
process.start()
```

And items. Items are not located in this folder but in spiders folder :

```
class ScrapybotItem(scrapy.Item):
 ean = scrapy.Field()
 desc = scrapy.Field()
 price = scrapy.Field()
 company = scrapy.Field()
```

I call them this way in both spiders :

```
from spiders.items import ScrapybotItem
```

My concern is that, pipelines doesnt open. I have in terminal :

```
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
```

It worked at one moment, I tested pipelines with CSVItemExporter. but for one reason now my pipelines doesnt open, even in the basic form I posted. Any idea ?

Comment: 1. It may be because that the settings are not being properly loaded when starting the Scrapy crawl process. Can you inspect (e.g. adding debugging output) on the return values of `get_project_settings()`?
2. One of the possible reasons is that there's something wrong the project file layout. E.g. missing `scrapy.cfg` file? (or incorrect content?)
3. Can you show further details on the project (e.g. the file layout, more job logs), or even better, create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks starrify for answering me ! How do you do for 1/ ? I tried to print (get_project_settings()) and had : <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x00000163021AAB38> but I guess it's not the way to proceed ! Also, pipelines work very well on command line... but not with script so really there might be an issue on this side... 2/ Scrapy cfg is [settings]
default = scrapybot.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = scrapybot  ... for me thats sound correct ? 3/ I'll edit my post asap to provide further details if it can help

Comment: mmh its weird i tried again and now it opens but doesnt print all data into CSV... i'll investigate this point ! Pipelines seem much complicate to use than the simple -o extract.csv !